# Socket input stream continuously returning null on readLine when Client disconnected by IntelliJ

Tags: java, sockets, intellij-idea, serversocket

I have a simple TCP server:

```
public class ServerSocketRunner {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9000);

    while (true) {
      Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

      new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("New client connected");
        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));) {

          String inputLine, outputLine;
          do {
            inputLine = in.readLine();
            System.out.print("Received: " + inputLine);
            String serverResponse = "Message Received: " + now();
            System.out.println("Sending: " + serverResponse);
            out.println(serverResponse);
          } while (!"bye".equals(inputLine));

          socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }).start();
    }
  }
}
```

and a client

```
public class ClientRunner {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 9000);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true)) {

      Scanner userEntry = new Scanner(System.in);
      String message, response;
      do {
        System.out.print("Enter message: ");
        message = userEntry.nextLine();
        output.println(message);
        response = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nSERVER> " + response);
      } while (!message.equals("bye"));
    }
  }
}
```

The client sends messages which user types, server responds with "Message received" and a timestamp. All works nicely, except for one scenario. If I close the client using IntelliJ, close and then "Disconnect" button

[image]

the server `readLine` continuously returns `null` and prints

```
Received: nullSending: Message Received: 2019-10-03T14:44:36.962
Received: nullSending: Message Received: 2019-10-03T14:44:36.962
Received: nullSending: Message Received: 2019-10-03T14:44:36.962
...
```

The IntelliJ **disconnect** behavior is explained [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/system-settings.html)

> Disconnect (if available) ---> If this option is selected, the running process is disconnected.

So, this would mean that the disconnect keeps the process running, but the IntelliJ will no more be attached to it.
Still this does not explain why `readLine` is continuously returning `null`.

Anyone can explain this behavior?

Comment: Seems "userEntry.nextLine();" reads empty stream and sends "/n"

Comment: `null` isn't an 'empty message', and it certainly isn't an 'empty message with newline'. It is an end of stream indication, and you are ignoring it. Close the socket and break. NB There is no such thing as a 'ServerSocket read'. Please correct your title and your question.

Comment: @y.bedrov Not possible, and no evidence of that is present.

Comment: @user207421 fair points, thanks. Corrected

Comment: Not really. You are still alleging that you are reading via a `ServerSocket`. This is impossible. You are reading via a `Socket`. And the server doesn't 'continuously receive null'. It continuously *returns* null from `readLine()`, for the reason I already stated, but it isn't continuously *receiving* anything.

Comment: @user207421 edited again ;)

Comment: Right, and now you've got the point of describing everytning correctly, including this: 'still this does not explain why `readLine()` is continuously returning null', you've answered your own question. All you had to do was look it up. This is the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client has been disconnected, and so the connection between client and server has been broken. But your code isn't handling that. When the connection is broken, that constitutes "end of stream" and the `BufferedReader`'s `readLine` function returns `null`. And that's exactly what it's telling you in the output:

```
Received: null [...]
```

You need to check for the `null` return value and break out of your loop.

```
    inputLine = in.readLine();
    if (inputLine == null) {
        System.out.print("Client disconnected. Leaving\n");
        break;
    }
```

Both client and server should do that test. In a real network, you never know when your peer is going to vanish.

See documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine-- (**Returns:** ... *or null if the end of the stream has been reached*)

(I don't know exactly what's going on in IntelliJ here, but obviously the server thread is still running. Server and client presumably are running in separate sub-processes or threads.)